# Save vf page as attachment in custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, controller

I have a dynamic virtual page that I create, and I would like to know if it was possible to save it as html (not pdf as I need to do some modification later on) inside my related files for a custom object

Then I would go to my custom object, the vfpage would be saved and I would modify some data inside and render it as pdf when all the changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getContent()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm).

> The content of the returned Blob depends on how the page is rendered. If the page is rendered as a PDF file, it returns the PDF document. If the page is not rendered as PDF, it returns HTML. To access the content of the returned HTML as a string, use the toString Blob method.

You can use `toString` and save the HTML string in 1 of the fields with data type text area.